The phrasal verb "keep after someone" in the past tense

keep after sb
to ask someone again and again to do something until they do it.
Tony's children and relatives kept after him to stop drinking.

[Longman Phrasal Verbs Dictionary]
The definition above of "keep at sb" contains "until they do it", but The Cambridge Phrasal Verbs Dictionary's definition of it does not have anything like "until they do it".
Does the example sentence above imply that Tony stopped drinking?

The phrase "until they do it" in the definition does not actually assert that the person actually "does it," rather it describes when "keeping after someone" would cease.  If I say: "I will keep speaking out until you till me to stop," I leave open whether you will actually tell me to stop or not.

It's not a strong implication, but you could probably infer that Tony stopped drinking (or that Tony died, which has the same effect)
But it would not be wrong to say "In the 1990s, his friends kept after him to stop drinking, but by 2000 they had given up. He continues to drink heavily to this day."

I don't think there is any particular automatic implication, and any consequence or later event(s) would need to be explicitly mentioned. Tony's children and relatives kept after him to stop drinking, until he stopped/emigrated/died/reduced his consumption. Tony's children and relatives kept after him to stop drinking but he took no notice and outlived them all, dying at the age of 116 years and 54 days.

@JamesK Thank you, JamesK. Is "keep after somebody" commonly used in BrE? Cambridge Phrasal Verbs Dictionary labels it "American".

@Kaguyahime - the (imaginary, figurative) 'membrane' that separates AmE and BrE is exceedingly porous in both directions. Maybe more so in the direction USA ==> UK.

@Kaguyahime - if a certain 'critical mass' of UK people have been exposed to some USian usage, whether because of movies, TV dramas, the Internet, Tik-Tok, whatever, they start using it, their friends and colleagues do, and before you know it, it's in the bloody dictionary!

The sentence "Tony's children and relatives kept after him to stop drinking" doesn't necessarily imply that Tony stopped drinking. The phrase "kept after him" means they continually urged or pressured him to stop, but it doesn't guarantee that he actually did.
The sentence only conveys that his children and relatives persisted in asking him to stop drinking, but Tony's response or outcome isn't specified. He might have eventually stopped, or he might not have.
If we rephrase the sentence, then it will indicate that Tony stopped drinking.
"Tony's children and relatives kept after him until he finally stopped drinking.".
Without the added phrase, Tony's actions are left unclear as the original text merely discusses the constant pressure he faces from his loved ones..
